# Is it possible to set a variable value as '0' or 'NaN' if the row data doesn't exist in a 'count' table?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am running code that loops through various csv files. I am pulling values out of a 'describe' box to create a new table (exported to a new csv). The issue I am having it that a few of my csv input files have fewer variables than others, therefore, I am running into an `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds` issue.

To overcome this, I wanted to ask if it is possible to force a '0' or NaN value for a variable if the underlying data is not present?

```
dfcount = df.groupby('value_x').count()

# For most files, this gives the following output:

                       logtime  zone    value_y
value_x             
Variable1              6456     6456    6456
Variable2              62       62      62
Variable3              1605     1605    1605

# For 'Case B' few files I get:

                       logtime  zone    value_y
value_x             
Variable1              6456     6456    6456
Variable3              1605     1605    1605
```

I then try to pull the individual values to add to a new csv, however, I would like to force a 'NaN' or 'O' value if, for example Variable2 isn't in the output table (which is currently causing the error):

```
df1 = dfcount.iloc[0]['value_y']
df2 = dfcount.iloc[1]['value_y']
df3 = dfcount.iloc[2]['value_y']
```

I have found several posts about doing this within MySQL, but not using Python. Thanks for any help!

Comment: you could create an empty dataframe that has all the values, then do some merges to fill in the data that is present leaving the blanks as `NaN` or `0`s as you see fit.

Comment: Great idea @Datanovice, will try it out and update with what I come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use a dictionary

- Don't hardcode variable assignments.
- `v[-1:]` gets the last value from `Variable1`, `1` in this case.

  - `f'df{v[-1:]}'` makes the key name `df1`
  - This way the df number will correspond to the variable number, given the format in the example.
- Instead of `df_dict[f'df{v[-1:]}']`, use `df_dict[v]`, then the `key` will be the variable name.
- A dictionary can easily be written to a csv, using [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)

  - When you write to a csv, it has defined headers. If the dict is missing one of the headers (keys), that column will be blank. **There is no need to have a dummy variable with `0` or `np.nan`.**

```py
import pandas as pd

# create a sample dataframe
case1 = {'value_x': ['Variable1', 'Variable2', 'Variable3'],
         'logtime': [6456, 62, 1605],
         'zone': [6456, 62, 1605],
         'value_y': [6456, 62, 1605]}

dfcount = pd.DataFrame(case1)
dfcount.set_index('value_x', inplace=True)

           logtime  zone  value_y
value_x                          
Variable1     6456  6456     6456
Variable2       62    62       62
Variable3     1605  1605     1605

# create a dictionary
df_dict1 = dict()

# use a loop to add dataframes to the dictionary
for v in dfcount.index:
    df_dict1[f'df{v[-1:]}'] = dfcount.loc[v]['value_y']

# access dataframes just like a dict
df_dict1['df1']
>>> 6456

print(df_dict1)
>>> {'df1': 6456, 'df2': 62, 'df3': 1605}
```

### Example with only Variable1 & Variable3

```
case2 = {'value_x': ['Variable1', 'Variable3'],
         'logtime': [6456, 1605],
         'zone': [6456, 1605],
         'value_y': [6456, 1605]}

dfcount = pd.DataFrame(case2)
dfcount.set_index('value_x', inplace=True)

           logtime  zone  value_y
value_x                          
Variable1     6456  6456     6456
Variable3     1605  1605     1605

# create a dictionary
df_dict2 = dict()

# use a loop to add dataframes to the dictionary
for v in dfcount.index:
    df_dict2[f'df{v[-1:]}'] = dfcount.loc[v]['value_y']

print(df_dict2)
>>> {'df1': 6456, 'df3': 1605}
```

### Write to csv

- This has all the keys being written as `df_dict[v]`, where `v` is each variable.

```py
import csv

t = [df_dict1, df_dict2]

csv_columns = ['Variable1', 'Variable2', 'Variable3']
with open('count.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
    writer.writeheader()
    for data in t:
        writer.writerow(data)

# resulting csv
Variable1,Variable2,Variable3
6456,62,1605
6456,,1605
```